# Как получить DevTools -> Sources через selenium в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

Сумел с помощью Selenium залогиниться на сайте и попасть на нужную мне страницу, но кроме самой страницы мне нужны её ресурсы. [Пробовал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861775/python-selenium-accessing-html-source) `driver.page_source`, но это не совсем то, что мне нужно — там лишь сгенерированный HTML-код страницы. Смотрел [документацию по Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) — не нашёл там что-то полезное, связанное с DevTools.

Конкретно говоря, мне нужна выделенная ниже на скриншоте страница **«4cb66...»**, причём в чистом виде (т.е. там прописан скрипт, запускающийся при старте страницы и генерирующий другой HTML-код, а мне нужен именно этот скрипт, поэтому-то Sources и использую), но, поискав на Stackoverflow, касательно своего вопроса я ничего не нашёл. Как быть?

[image: Фото Sources в DevTools]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил обычны get-запросом, используя requests:

```py
import requests
html = requests.get('link').content
```

Удивительно, но такая конструкция отдаёт сырой или, лучше сказать, непрепарированный HTML-код страницы.